# How should a 409 response be handled by a microservice?

Tags: http, error-handling, microservices, error-code

Consider two microservices "A" and "B". Say "A" does a POST call to "B" and "B" performs an operation which checks for duplicate request based on some id. If the operation is successful, the "B" returns a 200 OK response. If "B" finds that the request was a duplicate one it returns `409`.

Now consider a scenario wherein "A" makes a POST call To "B". "B" successfully processes but before it could respond, the connection times out and "A" receives `504` timeout error code. When service "A" retries the request, this time "B" recognizes this as a duplicate request and returns a `409` response as it has successfully processed the first request made by "A". In this case should service "A" consider this as a non-retriable error or should it consider this as a success (assuming its first request got processed successfully)?

Answer (score 0):

> ..."B" recognizes this as a duplicate request and returns a 409
>   response...In this case should service "A" consider this as a
>   non-retriable error or should it consider this as a success...

Can the caller draw firm conclusions as to whether the 409 status was caused by the "success" of their previous call, or by a "conflict" of a different kind? I don't know but I probably wouldn't want my handling to depend on this.

It's questionable whether any 4xx response status should ever be considered "retriable". In my opinion, handling should assume that the call failed permanently.

Comment: sometimes network failures can cause connection reset which may lead to return of a 5xx code to the caller ("A"). In that case, the microservice "B" probably does not have any way to know that caller ("A") did not get a 2XX and instead got a 5XX code.

Comment: @adi I agree it can happen. Network failures are however very infrequent and are handled by a retry policy, as you pointed out in your question. However, I have removed the first part of my answer as it's off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I read from your Q that B recognizes the next call as duplicate, even though timeout occurred. Firstly, don't depend/rely on it as a success. I would rather look for where is that state maintained? How long is it stored, in an event of a timeout either that state can be freed or check must be triggered from A to B to know if that transaction was actually successful?. For instance, A Posts customer info, B timeout. Now, before you retry, call a getCustomerInfo(cusomerName, customerId, x,y,z,...) to verify that even though timeout occurred, Post was successful at the end under the hood.

Also, you may want to do a deep-dive on how long is the hold, on the state of duplicate Id at B, and if you can work with the B team to have this released early to proceed further?

I also see an opportunity to have this choreographed between microservice A and B teams, and in such cases, a queuing service can turn out to be very beneficial (only if this is a frequently occurring situation).